# Spacing within a box, relative to the page

Tags: spacing, margins, boxes, geometry

I am attempting to place a textbox precisely 75mm from the top edge of a page (to correspond with a cut-out on the cover). On printing this out, I noticed I was getting positioning problems, so got rid of the 75mm space to debug and end up with a ugly space preceding the parbox. [image: Ugly space up the top]

The TeX code at this point is:

```
%% LyX 2.0.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm,headheight=0cm,headsep=0cm,footskip=1cm}
\usepackage{calc}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newgeometry{layoutsize={210mm,297mm},layoutoffset={0mm,0mm},left=0cm,bottom=0cm,top=0cm,right=0cm,noheadfoot}

\noindent %
\framebox{\begin{minipage}[t][65mm]{133mm}%
\vspace{5mm}


\begin{center}
A beautiful title goes here
\par\end{center}%
\end{minipage}}

\newpage{}

\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

Ok, so my next step is to eliminate the 5mm space which nicely formats the text relative to the box. Success! (of sorts) The ugly space is eliminated at the top, but this comes at the expense of the nice formatting space.
[image]

So I have two questions:
1) Why?!
2) How do I format such that I keep the nice formatting space between the text and the box whilst keeping the box flush with the edge of the page?

I have the latest geometry package (or so I would think - I downloaded from here http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry a couple of days ago). I've read the geometry user manual (and mucked about with \newgeometry) but still can't make sense of it all. I'm also using Lyx 2.0.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 (and also a bit of a noob when it comes to LaTeX).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: if i were trying to put a box in an exact position on a page, i would set it as an element of the running head, which is always located in a "dependable" place.  I would adjust the spacing so that the box effectively has zero depth (in plain tex, this would be accomplished using `\vss`, but i'm sure you can find the latex equivalent by searching in this forum).  this will "overlay" the box on the rest of the page.  (i'm "on the road", more than 6500 miles from my reference library.)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke - no worries.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Given my lack of latex experience I find your answer a little 'intimidating' - care to be more specific, maybe more code?

Comment: @Charlie -- i really can't give any code now, but i'll be back home in a few days, where i have a system on which i can test what i recommend.  i'll work on a "real" answer then.  hope that's okay.